# Android Layouts - Make EditText Lines Evenly Sized

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android app development, and while I understand the coding aspects just fine so far, I cannot wrap my mind around layouts. I am trying to create an app in which the `EditText` elements are evenly sized despite the size of their `TextView` counterparts. What the app looks like right now is on the left, and what I want is on the right.

[image: App Layout]

Here's the code for my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".RandApp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="@string/one"
                android:id="@+id/lblOne"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtOne"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="@string/two"
                android:id="@+id/lblTwo"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtTwo"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="@string/three"
                android:id="@+id/lblThree"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtThree"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </TableRow>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What could I do to achieve the desired effect? The layout code was created mostly using Android Studio's designer with only several small changes made by me.

Comment: try giving weight to textview and edittext both with width 0dp for each

Answer (score 1):

Try using weight..

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="one"
                android:id="@+id/lblOne"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="2" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtOne"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="two"
                android:id="@+id/lblTwo"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="2" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtTwo"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="three"
                android:id="@+id/lblThree"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="2" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtThree"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </TableRow>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. How does weight work? I cannot figure out what it is supposed to do and how I can make them weights appear proportional (the third label and text input is off a bit, especially when you turn the device sideways).

Answer (score 1):

## Here is my code

Simplest way ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="Blah"
android:textSize="15dp" />


<EditText
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="Blah"
android:textSize="15dp" />

<EditText
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Feel free to ask anything.. Happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Wouldn't this layout have issues with different screen dimensions?

Comment: yes to overcome this issue you need to use dimensions and give it to the text size which i  statically given to the edittext.